# Возможно ли отозвать голос за переоткрытие?

Tags: поддержка, переоткрытие-вопросов

Предположим, я проголосовал за переоткрытие вопроса, но потом передумал. Если я опять нажимаю на переоткрытие под вопросом, выходит следующее предложение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Отсюда вопрос - возможно ли как-то отозвать голос за переоткрытие (аналогично тому, как можно отозвать голос за закрытие)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это невозможно, но [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193061/295232) есть предложение на Meta Stack Exchange. Это не было реализовано из-за проблемы UX:

> This would be very dangerous from a UX perspective. The dialogs would need to look very different so users don't accidentally retract their reopen votes thinking they were casting one because they forgot they already voted. With the confirmation dialog we currently use, it's not possible to modify the appearance, so simply changing the text is a horrible idea. We'd have to actually build our own dialogs for these situations in order to prevent confusion.